# How would I add up each individual average created from a method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have this program that calculates each persons test score average and it counts each student. I need to print the class average and I know that I just need to add up the averages and then divide by the number of students, my issue is I'm not sure how to actually add up the averages and I'm just a little stuck - any help would be appreciated!
Here's my code:

public class GradeAnalyzer {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    
    Student students[] = new Student[30];
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("student_grades.txt"));
    int studentCount = 0;
    String name;
    double average = 0;

    while(scan.hasNext()){
        int score[]= new int[5];
        name=scan.next();
        for(int i=0;i<score.length;i++) {
            score[i]=scan.nextInt();
            
        }
        students[studentCount++]=new Student(name, score);
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<students.length;i++) {
        
        //I assume I would put it here, but I'm pretty sure I could also put it in the for loop above as well 
        
    }
    
    double classAverage = average/studentCount;
```

and my calculateAverage method:
public class Student {

```
private String name;
private char grade;
private double average;
private int score[] = new int[5];

public Student(String name, int[] score) {
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
    calculateAverage();
    calculateGrade();
}

public double calculateAverage() {
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
        sum+=score[i];
    }
        average = sum/score.length;
        return average;
}
```

Comment: You'll need a method on `Student` which returns the value of `average`. Then you can sum the average mark of each student just as you summed the scores for a single student.

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating the average of each student but you are not retrieving it. You can keep calculating it through the constructor and just add a getter for the average of each student.

```
public double getAverage() {   
    return average;
}
```

I would try something like this:

```
 while(scan.hasNext()){
        int score[]= new int[5];
        name=scan.next();
        for(int i=0;i<score.length;i++) {
            score[i]=scan.nextInt();
        }
        students[studentCount]=new Student(name, score);
        average += students[studentCount].getAverage(); 
        studentCount++;
    }
  double classAverage = average/studentCount;
```

Also you won't need to let the method Calculate Average to return anything so you can leave it as a void method like so:

```
public void calculateAverage() {
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
        sum+=score[i];
    }
        average = sum/score.length;
}
```